# How to Fix Run Time Error

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

I have a access program that let's the users click a button that will generate a backlog report, and display it then output that report to a folder on this path: 
`S:\ALC MASTER\Month End Reports - 2015\Senior Management\2015 Backlog Report`

But for some reason I keep getting a run time error even though the file is being outputted to that folder even with the error. I just want to know if there is a way to suppress that error.

Here is My code:

```
Dim MonthStart As Integer
Dim MonthEnd As Integer

For i = 1 To DLookup(DMax("[rsu]", "[RSU totals]", ""), "[RSU totals]", "") Step 1
    If DCount("*", "[RSU totals]", "[rsu] = " & i) > 0 Then

        If Date < "#8/01/" & Year(Now) & "#" Then
            setDate = "7/01/" & Year(Now)
            rptName = "Sales Forecast Detail - Jan-Jun"
        Else
            setDate = "13/01/" & Year(Now)
            rptName = "Sales Forecast Detail - Jul-Dec"
        End If

        fileDirName = "S:\ALC MASTER\Month End Reports - " & Year(Now) & "\" & "Senior Management" & _
        "\" & Year(Now) & " Backlog Report" & "\" & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mm") & "-" & _
        Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmm") & " - " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, setDate), "mmm") & ".pdf"

        DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewReport, , "[rsu] = " & i
        Reports(rptName).ReportFooter.Visible = Flase
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, rptName, "PDF Format(*.pdf)", fileDirName, True
        DoCmd.Close acReport, rptName

    End If
Next
```

Comment: What run time error do you get?

Comment: Runs a query called RSU totals tallies up the recorders then runs the loop for every record found.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my problem was i was looping through reports that didn't exist. Taking out the For loop and the initial If statement worked.